# OpenCvSharp detect many part into image

Tags: c#, opencv

What is the best way to do research on several types of images.
These are complex images that are really different.
I use MatchTemplate for each image I search for in a video.
I need to know what kind of image I'm looking for every time.

Is this the right way to do it? To make a treatment for each part of the image that I seek?

```
Mat finderone = ...........;
Mat findertwo = ...........;
Mat finder... = ...........;


var res1 = matSource.MatchTemplate(finderone,TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed)
var res2 = matSource.MatchTemplatefindertwo,TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed)
var res3 = matSource.MatchTemplate(.... , TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach can be adequate, but it has several limitations. Your patterns shouldn't be rotated, scaled or occluded.

There are several other methods for image detection. For example, based of feature points, such as SURF, SIFT and so on. OpenCV has good tutorial about finding known object at the image: [feature homography](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)

It can be easily realized with opencvsharp too.

If `MatchTemplate` meets your requirements, and you want just to optimize your code, than it is impossible, because `MatchTemplate` can't work with multiple templates in a time. The best thing you can do, it to improve readability of your code and structure your templates to single array of mats and check it in the loop:

```
Mat[] templates = new Mat[] { finderone, finder..., finder_N };
Mat[] results = new Mat[templates.Lenght];
for (int i = 0; i < templates.Length; ++i) {
    results[i] = sourceMat.MatchTemplate(templates[i], TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed);
}
```